# What is the sign of the result when applying the implicit function theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, implicit-differentiation

Suppose I have some function that $g$ that satisfies

$$g (..)=\frac{a}{f(x)(x+a)^2}=1$$

Using the implicit function theorem, I can see when an increase in $a$ results in an increase in $x$:

$$-\frac{\partial g/\partial a}{\partial g/\partial x}= - \frac{x-a}{a(a+x)f'(x)+2f(x)a}$$

Am I applying this correctly? And is the negative sign before $\frac{\partial g/\partial a}{\partial g/\partial x}$ necessary?

---

So when $a>x$, an increase in $a$ results in an increase in $x$, assuming that $a(a+x)f'(x)+2f(x)a$ is positve?

Comment: Comes from total differential

Comment: What comes from the total differential?

Comment: The negative sign

Comment: $$ dg(x,a)=g_1(x,a)dx+g_2(x,a)da=0\implies \frac{dx}{da}=-g_2(x,a)/g_1(x,a)$$So, yes, the negative sign is needed.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you! Could you try answer the updated part too. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that under presumed smoothness conditions, we have

$$dg(x,a)=\frac{\partial g(x,a)}{\partial a}\,da+\frac{\partial g(x,a)}{\partial x}\,dx$$

On the surface $g(x,a)\equiv 1$, $dg(x,a)=0$.  Hence,

$$\frac{dx}{da}=- \frac{\frac{\partial g(x,a)}{\partial a}}{\frac{\partial g(x,a)}{\partial x}}$$